# Split row with 3 columns into two rows with 2 columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have got a table in which one row will be splitted into two rows with different columns.

[Input table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9phV.png)

[Output table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeAUT.png)

As you can see, except `Date` every column remains constant for each `ID`, so I would like to get every row with unique `ID`, copy it (so I have got 2 rows of each `ID`) and then in one row in `3rd column` I would have `Interest Rate` value while in 2nd row `Depreciation` value.

Is it possible to do it using formulas or VBA?

Comment: Please, show us what you tried by your own. You can use a dictionary to extract the unique keys and line item the two columns value in an array or in a string separated by a character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It uses a dictionary, as I recommended in my comment and then processes its keys/items in order to output `arrFin`, dropped at once in range "G2"):

```
Sub UniqueCompact()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, arr, arrFin, i As Long, dict As Object
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastRow = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row
  arr = sh.Range("A2:E" & lastRow).value 'place the range in an array for faster iteration
  
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")              'set the dictionary
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    dict(arr(i, 1)) = Array(arr(i, 3), arr(i, 4), arr(i, 5))        'fill the dictionary
  Next i
 
  ReDim arrFin(1 To dict.count * 2, 1 To 3) 'redim the final array to kep two rows per a dictionary key
  Dim k As Long: k = 1
  For i = 0 To dict.count - 1
        arrFin(k, 1) = dict.Keys()(i): arrFin(k, 2) = dict.Items()(i)(0): arrFin(k, 3) = dict.Items()(i)(1): k = k + 1
        arrFin(k, 1) = dict.Keys()(i): arrFin(k, 2) = dict.Items()(i)(0): arrFin(k, 3) = dict.Items()(i)(2): k = k + 1
  Next i
  'drop the pocessed array content in G2:
  sh.Range("G2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).value = arrFin
End Sub
```

I am making now an exception, supposing that you do not know the community rules, but we here do not offer free code writing services. When place another question, please read the rules and fully comply.

Send some feedback after testing it. If something unclear, do not hesitate to ask for clarification. Our main goal here is **to make people learning**.

Comment: @Saguro Didn't you find some time to test the above code? If tested, didn't it do what you need?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It worked just perfect. I do know the rules but I'm begginer in Excel and VBA and didn't know how complex functions I can implement, but thanks to that code I can see it's not that far from MATLAB programming and basing on it next coding will be lot easier. Great Thanks!